# hive date conversion not working

Tags: date, datetime, hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp

I am trying to compare two dates in different format. So, I am converting both of them to unixtimespamp to compare but since they have different date formats. its not converting the right way. I need help with this. Here's my query:

```
select a.date,b.date
from table1 a join table2 b
on (from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(b.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a')))=(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(nvl(a.date,'3050-01-01 00:00:00.0'))));
```

The date formats are:

```
a.date                  b.date
4/12/2016 5:46:50 PM    2016-04-12 17:46:50.0
4/12/2016 5:46:50 PM    2016-04-12 17:46:50.0
```

Thanks a lot,
stacky

Comment: Date format for a.date: 4/12/2016 5:46:50 PM                                           Date format for b.date: 2016-04-12 17:46:50.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got your date treatments backwards. `a.date` is the one that you need to specify format for. `b.date` should convert nicely into a timestamp without any prep. The following tested well on my machine:

```
select a.date,b.date
from table1 a join table2 b
on unix_timestamp(b.date) = unix_timestamp(a.date,'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are converting the date into long int. which is more accurate. So why not just compare them to see they are equal. here is the query:

```
   select a.date,b.date from table1 a join table2 b on (unix_timestamp(b.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a'))=(unix_timestamp(coalesce(a.date,'3050-01-01 00:00:00.0')));
```